# WebAPI works ok one Azure web app but I get 404 on another

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, routes, http-status-code-404, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app which works fine on my development web app on Azure (free) - the webapi routing works and actions are executed ok.  But on my production web app (shared tier, if that makes any difference?!) it returns 404 - even the most simple web api controller. It's the exact same code for both. I've looked into this extensively but I cannot find a reason why it would not work. Again, locally it works fine. I've pretty much run out of ideas and cannot find any answers online. Has anyone else experienced this or have any suggestions? Many thanks

Comment: how did you deploy your app? if you deploy to a different site that in shared tier, can you repro the same 404 error?

Comment: I deployed from VS2015 using Web deploy and by FTP - same result. When I created another web app in the same shared tier it worked fine!

Comment: for the the site that have issue, can you go to "https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole", navigate to D:\home\site\wwwroot, can you see if the contents are there?

Comment: It all seems to be there. Obviously the web API controllers are compiled. All the dlls I expect to see in /bin are there. It must be something to do with the routing?

Comment: it could be routing, but before going too deep into it, i would suggest you to download the whole "wwwroot" folder (click download on the folder you should have a zip). Download one from the broken site and also download from a working site. in your local machine use diff tool try to compare the two to see if there is any file missing. i would expect there would be some difference.

Comment: I've done that and don't see much different. The prod site has some ApplicationInsights dlls that the test site does not. I also compared with my free tier development site - again no real difference.